# The term 'node' is not recognized... In Powershell

Tags: windows, node.js, powershell, npm

I have been trying to resolve this issue for the whole day.

When I run `node -v` or `npm install` in cmd prompt, it works absolutely fine. But when I run the same commands in Powershell, it gives the following error:s

```
PS C:\Users\Anubhav.Trivedi> node -v
The term 'node' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelli
ng of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:5
+ node <<<<  -v
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (node:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I tried uninstalling node js and reinstalling it. Added node js path `C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\` to enviroment variables (system variables). Restarting computer. But nothing seems to work. 
Kindly let me know, what am I missing here.

Comment: Check that the folder really is in your path. This will return a value if it is: `$env:path -split ';' | Select-String nodejs` Did you remember to restart the PowerShell console when you updated the Path environment variable?

Comment: Please put an answer and  flag the question as answered.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As dan-gph mentioned check the `Path` in environment variable using script `$env:path -split ';' | Select-String nodejs` and once you update the `Path` in environment variable, make sure to restart `powershell` and also restart `explorer.exe`. This would resolve the issue.

If you still face issues, check which nodejs you have installed (32bit or 64bit). Install 32 bit only as powershell or cmd are 32bit programs

Comment: Hi! Would it be too much to ask about what it does exactly. It solved my issue here. Thanks!

Answer (score 47):

These issues cannot be installed from the Package Manager console, so I had to browse lot of things to fix the issues and finally I got the solution.

Maybe we followed these scenarios

- Missing Node.js software
- Wrongly updated Windows environment path
- Installed in the wrong path
- Old version of Node.js software

You can download the latest [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) software here.

**Update Path**

After installation, automatically create nodejs folder in this path “C:\Program Files (x86)” or “C:\Program Files “.

Open Control Panel -> User Accounts -> Change my environmental variable and verify the path Variable value “C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs” or “C:\Program Files\nodejs “.

new => user = path => value = C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs  and after apply that.

and close Editor and restart it. it will work correctly.

**note** :- enter your path instead of copy of this path.

Comment: i work with visual studio code 1.41 and get this error, i put the environmental variable and it work for me.

Comment: A simple IDE (VScode) restart did it for me! Thanks

Comment: I am using Windows 11 as OS and found out that the path was not added during installation for some reason so had to add it and it worked like a charm. Path in my case : C:\Program Files\nodejs

Comment: @Skromak you legend!!

Answer (score 12):

Model for VSCode editor

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin
```

1. Search **PATH** environment variable.
2. Add the above paths into the Environment variables (both user
   variable path and system variable path).
3. Restart VSCode.
4. Open a new terminal in VSCode
5. run `node --version` output should equal `v16.13.0`

Comment: This worked for me. In case you're confused, the first path is for the user variable and the second path is for the system variable.

Comment: Just a follow-up... While node was working fine, npm was not. However, it's already been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24721903/npm-npm-cli-js-not-found-when-running-npm#answer-24741740

Answer (score 3):

If you installed NodeJs recently after opening the IDE like Visual Studio Code or any other IDE that includes the terminal you are trying. then try this.

1. Restart the IDE, If you installed NodeJs recently after opening the IDE like Visual Studio Code or any other IDE that includes the terminal you are trying.
2. Restart the CommandLine if you installed NodeJs after you opened the CommandLine.

I hope it will be fixed most of the time by following these simple steps.

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1):

Was looking for a solution about an hour, this actually worked:
This manually resets the path variable in the specific PowerShell terminal.

```
$env:Path = `
[System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path","Machine") + ";" + `
[System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path","User")
```

Answer (score 1):

Restarting the computer did work for me.

I know you did try, but it might be useful for other facing similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

open control panel then--

```
   user accounts
         |
   user accounts
         |
  change my environment variables
         |
        new 
         |
  (In variable name use)--Path
         |
  (In variable value use)C:\Program Files\nodejs
         |
        ok
```

After that just restart you terminal

Answer (score 0):

chances are that you messed up with your system path, if it's the case, a very straight forward solution will be re-installing node and npm but don't forget to close and re-open powershell/cmd

Note: i thought that restarting computer has no effect on path but in an accident someone just deplug my laptop from power and after i turned it on everything was repaired and OK!

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same error. Simply check below instructions. If all they are done. Just restart your computer. Then it will worked for me. I just restarted my computer.

1. List item
2. Missing Node.js software
3. Wrongly updated Windows environment path
4. Installed in the wrong path

Answer (score 0):

1.find nodejs folder

2. go to environment variable in windows
3. edit path and add "find nodejs folder"
4. Restart computer
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

This issue corrected after updated my environment variable path
i just copy the path from path value in user to path value in system check image attachment.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/11uCk.png

[path change image below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11uCk.png)

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Control Panel\System and Security\System on Windows 10.
2. Go to advance properties.
3. Advance system settings -> advance system settings -> Environment Variables Or type `edit the system environment variables` in the windows search.
4. Add "C:\Program Files\nodejs" ,"C:\Program Files\nodejs" and "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin" to the user and system variable (path)
5. restart the cmd and run again.

Hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

if you are getting this error after installing node with nvm-windows, then you have forgotten to run the command `nvm use 19.3.0` use whichever version you have installed

Answer (score 0):

1. Uninstall all previous versions of `node`, if any.
2. Install [`nvm-windows`](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows). Go to [releases](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/releases), download `nvm-setup.exe` from the latest release.
3. Install using administrative privileges.
4. Run `PowerShell as Administrator`. Run `nvm -v` in the PowerShell to see the installed version of nvm-windows
5. Run `nvm ls` to see the list of installed versions of node. There should be none, as you have just installed nvm
6. Run `nvm on` to enable nvm, and set path variables
7. Now you can use `nvm` the same way, you would on Ubuntu or Mac.

   1. Run `nvm install 18` to install node v18
   2. Switch between node versions using `node use {node-version}`. e.g. To switch to node 16, run `nvm use 16`

Answer (score 0):

I put my node file that I had downloaded the latest version next to the javascript file and solved my problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If your folder or file name has a space or something like that, you need to remove those things from your folder or file and after that open that folder right-click on it and select open with vs code, which will solve your problem

Answer (score -1):

Reinstall/repair the application and close the vs code powershell