# The term 'node' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I'm getting this error while running node in my VS Code terminal besides I tried to run the same thing in CMD and it worked there but not in VS Code terminal:
[image]

```
node: The term 'node' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

At line:1 char:1
+ node
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (node:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: add node to your PATH and restart VSC

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The term 'node' is not recognized... In Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30318628/the-term-node-is-not-recognized-in-powershell)

Answer (score 31):

Try closing and then reopening VS Code.

If you have installed node while VS Code was opened then the change to the PATH won't be visible yet. (be sure that the add to PATH option is selected while installing node...if not be sure to add it to the PATH)

Comment: This helped me too, thanks. I had multiple Visual Studio Code windows open, I needed to close all of them.

Answer (score 23):

What worked for me was : open Visual Studio Code -> Terminal -> New Terminal

Everything else I tried didn't...

Comment: Same with me, thanks for saving my time.

Comment: Finally, this worked for me!! Thanks.

Answer (score 22):

I also got this error, I resolved it by opening Visual Studio Code with *Run as administrator* privilages (in Windows).

[image: Demo]

Comment: Thanks !!!  after all the possible solutions! This solution worked! I don't  know why vscode needs admin priveleges, as it worked fine earlier without it.

Comment: Thanks. This solution works. However, I wonder why this happens? I have not been able to find an answer.

Answer (score 2):

if you have anaconda installed,  everytime vscode the terminal, infact the vscode opens the conda environment,

you can solve it by typing,

conda install -c conda-forge nodejs

Comment: That's a huge help bro. You are the hero here. Thanks a lot.

Comment: btw, you can turn this feature of vs code of enabling conda environment automatically by entering
"conda config --set auto_activate_base False"
from 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64684533/10145774

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same error. And the solution I found is while reinstalling on the last step it asked if we wanted to install Choclatey and other few files that may be required, I unticked that option and Whola it worked. I dont know the technicality why it worked but it worked.

Comment: People pick on other people for spelling all the time on the internet, and I want you to make sure you know that's not what's happening here … it completely *made my day* to read that you type that as "whola." Just for future reference, if you really want to know, it's spelled … voilà. Absolutely beautiful. I loved it. Never change. ❤️

Comment: + Your tip resolved the issue, except when it asked me to press any key to install Choclatey,... I closed the window. It really deserved a Whola

Comment: English isn't my first language .
Nevertheless voilà I hope you understood the message I was trying to convey. Hehehe..

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, it's because I select an option to install chocolatey and python during installation process .
When I try to uninstall my node installed and try to reinstall without choosing option to install chocolatey and python it works for me ....
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WFvp.png)

Comment: please edit your answer and post code instead of image links.

Answer (score 0):

Add node to your environment variable using following steps.
If your operating system is windows 10,
Right click "**This PC**" -> **Properties**
[Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAySL.png)

Then click "**Advance system settings**" and click "**Environment Variable**" button as follow

[Environment variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEebX.png)

Then select the path and click **Edit** button
[User Variables for Administrator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UuU9N.png)

For the above error you have to add node js location.
Click **New** and add node file path.
C:\Program Files\nodejs

[File path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAytE.png)