# Stop conda when VSCode starts

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda, conda

I wanted to ask if someone can help me to Deactivate conda env when I start VSCode, everytime I open VSCode it starts conda env, i've search how to stop it but i didnt found a solution so everytime i have to deactivate it manually, has anyone face the same problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I prevent Conda from activating the base environment by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54429210/how-do-i-prevent-conda-from-activating-the-base-environment-by-default)

Answer (score 7):

Execute the following command on on VSCode terminal

```
conda config --set auto_activate_base False
```

It won't have conda base environment activated next time you open VSCode terminal.

****Note**: It will only work if you have done conda init at the time of installation.**

Hope, this answer will help you.

Comment: How to proceed with the conda init in VS code? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

check the Python interpreter you have selected. Choosing an interpreter from you env will activate the env. [Python: Select Interpreter](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments)