# How to prevent powershell from starting with virtual environment activated

Tags: python, powershell, pip, virtualenv, conda

When I start powershell it starts in a conda environment named `py37_default`. I have to type `conda deactivate` which brings me to `base`, and then enter `deactivate` to finally exit the environment entirely. How do I stop my powershell from starting off in these environments?

Comment: is it being activated in your powershell profile?

Comment: Hi, perhaps this post can be of some help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64684533/11246056

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I prevent Conda from activating the base environment by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54429210/how-do-i-prevent-conda-from-activating-the-base-environment-by-default)

Comment: Does this only happens when starting from PowerShell?

Answer (score 0):

The (py37_default) notation is there to tell you which virtual environment that you are on. This is very useful when you are using different environments on the same system.
You can stop it auto activating with `conda config --set auto_activate_base false`