# How to run JavaScript code in Visual Studio Code terminal?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

If I run JavaScript code in VS terminal by giving the command "node filename.js" it is showing the error

```
The term 'node' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ node index.js
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (node:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

How to fix this?

Comment: please see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59973785/the-term-node-is-not-recognized-as-the-name-of-a-cmdlet-function-script-file which is a duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30318628/the-term-node-is-not-recognized-in-powershell

Comment: On a side note, JavaScript (single word) does not have any relationship with Java, aside for the intentionally confusing name. This is an important caveat when looking for information online.

Comment: did you install NodeJS yet?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add path in environment variable.

Steps:

1. Search for path variable in you start menu
   [image: Setting name]
2. Select Environment Variable and edit path.
3. Add your node.js path in list.

[image: Path name for nodeJs folder.]

Comment: Don't forget to restart Visual Studio Code after adding the environment variable.