# Why does node.js not work in visual code?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I know this problem has been asked a few times, but I still couldn't find a correct answer for myself.

I have node.js installed in my 'C:\Program Files' folder, and I can run the node.js app.
When opening the command prompt I can also get the version of the node by typing 'node -v' which shows my node version v14.15.4.

But whenever I write this in VS Code terminal it shows me this error message:

node: The term 'node' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- node
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (node:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/30326375/28004

Comment: running in a separate terminal is better, the ide console is not height enough to see output

Comment: You could try adding the env variable for windows of `C:/users/<your name>/appData/roaming/npm`

Answer (score 3):

Restart VS Code and it should work. Restarting the computer is unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

Restart your computer, it'll work. I got the same error and it worked for me.