# VSCode not recognizing the term 'node' while CMD and PowerShell do

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I can run `node -v` in cmd and PowerShell just fine, but when I try to run it in vscode terminal using powershell, it doesn't recognize 'node', however, the terminal does recognize it when I run it under cmd.

**This is when using powershell in the terminal**
[image: Powershell in terminal]

**And this is when using cmd in the terminal**
[image: CMD in terminal]

Comment: Try restarting your VS code & then run it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The term 'node' is not recognized... In Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30318628/the-term-node-is-not-recognized-in-powershell)