# Windows 10 powershell 'node' not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

`PS C:\Users\DELL> node (OR) gcc --version (OR) g++ --version
node: The term 'node' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1`

- node
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (node:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

I m having a problem with my Windows 10 Powershell, whenever I tried to get run code of (node/c++/c) via VS code I am getting an error in PowerShell, I have tried restarting my laptop also tried Restarting PowerShell and edited environment paths still **I am having the same error I think my Powershell Files got corrupted!** please help me I am new to Stackoverflow and A student of B.Sc.IT so my vs code editor for learning purposes is also dependent on Powershell I get totally stuck !! , Thanks in advance!

**Due to Posting answer ban I m writing here hope it helps the community**

Actually, I have Tried the Following ways to solve this issue on windows 10~

- System Restore
- Powershell Restart
- Powershell Files Replace (with other window system's files in Program files..etc)
- Restart PC after troubleshooting
- Environment path change
  but didn't anything work...
  **But finally after windows 11 upgrade its automatically solved my issue**

> *I recommend you to install certain things(Apps, software, etc..)
> from the official Trusted website and do not tamper with system files
> unless necessary also avoid using Crack versions and multiple   .NET
> frameworks and installers on the same system unless necessary use only
> 1 INSTALLER OF .NET VISUAL STUDIO latest in my case I think it was the
> problem...!!*

Comment: What is output when you enter `$env:path` in the PowerShell console within VSCode?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add node to your PATH. Go to System->Environment Variables->System Variables. Edit the "Path" variable and add `C:\Program Files\nodejs`.

Comment: I have already like this ->C:\Program Files\nodejs in Environment variable but still, my issue is different according to this article this is my last hope and I tried it but not worked -->
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30318628