# NPM not working n Windows, after installing from nodejs server?

Tags: node.js, npm

I've installed latest version from Nodejs site 6.3.0. I checked the version, am able to get it. When checked version fro npm, unable to proceed further. Displaying error: "Cannot find module".

[image]

Comment: Have you tried this?: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24741740/1092711

Comment: Strange! It worked.