# npm-cli.js not found with the CLI command (in Windows 8.1 OS) npm -v

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to install nodejs and npm in my computer with Windows 8.1 - 64 bit. I downloaded the msi from the official nodejs web site and installed it. When I tried to check the version of node by typing *node -v*, it worked perfectly. But when I tried to check whether npm is installed properly by typing *npm -v*, the following error appears.
[image]

How to fix this.Can someone help me in this. I referred the answers of similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24721903/npm-cli-js-not-found-when-running-npm). And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39840006/npm-cli-js-not-found-on-git-bash) also.But it did not worked too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is could because of incorrect installation. Have you tried reinstallation of Node and NPM? If not, uninstall from Program and Features and follow this [walkthrough](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/install-node-js-npm-windows).

Also, need to set npm as global variable $PATH.

Comment: Actually it worked when I tried for the fourth time.