# unable to install @angular/cli

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am trying to install @angular/cli using npm. Below error I am getting while I am trying to install. What can I do for it?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TQ9z.png)

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24721903/npm-cli-js-not-found-when-running-npm

Comment: Possible duplicate of [npm-cli.js not found when running npm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24721903/npm-cli-js-not-found-when-running-npm)

Comment: Now It's working fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that problem is in env variables of `nodejs`.
Try set properly path to nodejs

```
SET PATH=C:\Program Files\Nodejs;%PATH%
```

Comment: I run it from command prompt. It is working fine. Thanks @Maxim

Comment: @DebasishHalder Great that it helped you!)