# npm start is not working npm (ERR! Failed at the apm@0.0.0 start script.)

Tags: angular, npm

I am using example in [link](https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-GettingStarted) to learn angular. but when I run **npm start** it shows error. I searched for solution it ask to update npm or angular version but I am already using latest as below

**npm -v = 6.4.1**

**node -v = 10.9.0**

**angular CLI = 6.1.5**

I am using windows 7

```
 > apm@0.0.0 start F:\Angular\Angular-GettingStarted-master\APM-Start
 > ng serve -o

 npm ERR! file bash
 npm ERR! path bash
 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
 npm ERR! errno ENOENT
 npm ERR! syscall spawn bash
 npm ERR! apm@0.0.0 start: `ng serve -o`
 npm ERR! spawn bash ENOENT
 npm ERR!
 npm ERR! Failed at the apm@0.0.0 start script.
 npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely 
 additional logging output above.

 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
 npm ERR!     C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-09- 
 05T16_12_41_076Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Which link are you using again? It didn't load as a part of this question. Please consider adding it again.

Comment: I updated link in question.

Comment: Did you run `npm install` before trying `ng serve`?

Comment: Also, if angular-cli isn't installed globally, after `npm install` you will have to run the command as follows `node_modules/.bin/ng serve` or `npm run start`.

Comment: You should be running `ng serve` instead of `npm start` I guess.

Comment: Yes ng serve solved the issue but now it shows error as 
ERROR in ./ansi-html
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '#' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

Comment: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/issues/518

Comment: It do not help. I really do not understand why this error shows. and how to fix it. I now created new project using ng new. and it gives same error  ERROR in ./ansi-html Module parse failed: Unexpected character '#' (1:0) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.`

Comment: Have you thought of starting from scratch again. I just downloaded it and everything worked fine. I am using VS Code, and apart from CLI (mine is lower version), every thing is same.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your node version seems to be too higher. Please downgrade node version to 8.9.0. (Confirm that your npm version also gets downgraded based on node).

Delete your `node_modules` folder.

Then run commands in sequence:

`npm cache clean --force`

`npm install`

`npm rebuild node-sass`

Then try: `ng serve`

Comment: I installed version 8.9.0 and npm  -v gives error 'Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Windows\System32\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'. I set environment variable to 'C:\Program Files\nodejs' still same error

Comment: there is no node_modules in System32

Comment: Did you install node as administrator? If not, try installing as administrator.

Comment: Yes I installed it as administrator

Comment: Seems that your node.js did not install correctly. Please uninstall all node.js versions from 'Control Panel'. Check if it's uninstalled properly using `node -v`. Then try again installing node 8.9.0. Still problem persists, refer this post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24721903/6848923 and try the solutions.

Comment: Finally it is working now after downgrade node and putting paths in environment variables

Comment: Good job. Happy for you.

Answer (score 1):

wow it was crazy. I solved this by

1. uninstalling node and restarting my Machine.
2. downloading a new version of node [from here](https://nodejs.org/en/) which was the LTS version
3. installed this new version of node i downloaded.
4. ran `npm cache clean --force`
5. ran `npm install` in the project directory.
   and voila its ALIVE!!! it worked.