# Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Node.js\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'

Tags: node.js

when I am running the following command  `npm install request cheerio`, I am facing this error:

[image]

I am not able to find the solution for this, please help me out.

Comment: try to remove your node_modules and package_lock.json and make npm i again

Comment: Possible duplicate of [npm-cli.js not found when running npm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24721903/npm-cli-js-not-found-when-running-npm)