# nodejs Can't find module

Tags: node.js, npm-install

I can successfully install node via `npm install` and I wanted to run `npm run dev` but it gives me this error

```
 $ npm run dev
 internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:584
 throw err;
 ^

 Error: Cannot find module 
 'C:\xampp\htdocs\lsapp\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'
 at Function.Module._load 
 (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:508:25)
 at Function.Module.runMain 
 (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:754:12)
 at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
 at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

I'm stuck for 4 days, already tried other possible solutions like removed node_modules, clean cache, re-install but it still gives the the same error above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24721903/npm-cli-js-not-found-when-running-npm