# EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\.staging

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

I'm trying to run npm install on my project but its showing EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules.staging

I don't have root administrative access. I'am using as local user in my system and my system is windows 10

node v10.16.3
npm  v6.11.3

Can any one please help me to resolve this issue. I'am requesting you guys please.

```
3235 error code EPERM
3236 error syscall mkdir
3237 error path C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\.staging
3238 error errno -4048
3239 error Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\.staging'
3239 error  { [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\.staging']
3239 error   cause:
3239 error    { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\.staging'
3239 error      errno: -4048,
3239 error      code: 'EPERM',
3239 error      syscall: 'mkdir',
3239 error      path: 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\.staging' },
3239 error   stack:
3239 error    'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir \'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\.staging\'',
3239 error   errno: -4048,
3239 error   code: 'EPERM',
3239 error   syscall: 'mkdir',
3239 error   path: 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\.staging',
3239 error   parent: 'nodemon' }
3240 error The operation was rejected by your operating system.
3240 error It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
3240 error or that you lack permissions to access it.
3240 error
3240 error If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
3240 error permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
3240 error the command again as root/Administrator.
3241 verbose exit [ -4048, true ]
```

Comment: Please brother's and sisters help me to solve this I'm requesting you all

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NPM: npm-cli.js not found when running npm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24721903/npm-npm-cli-js-not-found-when-running-npm)

Answer (score 21):

Try clearing the cache:

- `npm cache clean --force`

Or

1. `npm uninstall npm -g`
2. `npm install npm -g`

Or

- `npm set prefix 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm'`

The last one worked for me

Comment: escape the slashes and use double quotes `npm set prefix "%USERPROFILE%\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm"`

Answer (score 7):

run these commands:

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app

npm install -g create-react-app
```

that's will upgrade your npx, then run

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

Answer (score 3):

Open your command line (CMD) as an admin. 
Navigate to your project directory. 
Install the package globally e.g nodemon or any other npm package.

This worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

on windows 10

From Start Menu : type "CMD" then  "run as administrator"
then continue using "Node Commands"

Answer (score 2):

Delete 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm' folder or just rename it (like to 'npm_') to be on safe side, and then run command:

npm install

this will create 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm' folder again.

This worked for me.

Comment: man, u saved me, after days of unsuccessful solutions read all over the internet, this one worked for me.thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
npm cache clear

npm install npm -g
```

If you run the command **npm cache clear** get error, it means you don't have npm installed yet, just run the following command: **npm install npm -g**
Then close command prompt or visual studio code and run it again to take effect

Answer (score 0):

Today we ran into the same problem. It turned out that there was a environment variable set:

NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=C:\Program Files\Nodejs

Removing this environment variable fixed the problem fo us.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this issue...

Firstly you change your drive
c drive change make new drive D and then run your command

`D:\nodejs> vue create hello-world`

this is what worked for me