# npm update directory path confusion

Tags: node.js, npm

After running npm install -g npm to update from version 6.5.0 -> 6.14.6
per, the instructions at the end of running npm install on a project, npm path appears to be confused.
My environment path has it at ~.node_modules_global\node_modules\npm\bin however if I try to install another package I get this error

`Error: Cannot find module '~\.node_modules_global\node_modules\npm\bin\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'`

Notice that it is looking for a second node_modules folder, but that folder doesn't exist.
I'm on Windows 10
Why would that happen?

Comment: Please check the answer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24721903/npm-cli-js-not-found-when-running-npm

Comment: Thanks everyone for the suggestions. I cleared the paths, and reinstalled nodejs. Issue is now fixed.