# What is going on with nodeJS? It's throwing an error upon uninstall and reinstall

Tags: node.js, npm

This is now happening everytime i try to run any npm command

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:968
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:965:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:841:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:968
  throw err;
  ^
```

Comment: Have you tried running `npm install`?

Comment: this question answered before in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24721903/npm-cli-js-not-found-when-running-npm