# Can't update npm - npm ERR! Cannot find module 'update-notifier'

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, npm-install

I can't do `npm install` on Windows in my application in Angular 8, because I get error:

```
C:\Repository\Tools\Tools\ClientApp>npm install
npm ERR! code MODULE_NOT_FOUND
npm ERR! Cannot find module 'update-notifier'
npm ERR! Require stack:
npm ERR! - C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-02-19T13_09_42_358Z-debug.log
```

in log file:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\xxx\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.11
3 info using node@v14.15.5
4 verbose stack Error: Cannot find module 'update-notifier'
4 verbose stack Require stack:
4 verbose stack - C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
4 verbose stack     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
4 verbose stack     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
4 verbose stack     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
4 verbose stack     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
4 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js:87:22)
4 verbose stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11)
5 verbose cwd C:\Repository\Tools.xxx\Tools.xxx\ClientApp
6 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17763
7 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\xxx\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
8 verbose node v14.15.5
9 verbose npm  v6.14.11
10 error code MODULE_NOT_FOUND
11 error Cannot find module 'update-notifier'
11 error Require stack:
11 error - C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
12 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Any other command that I try to call causes the same result, for example:

```
npm i -g npm-upgrade
npm cache clean
npm install -g update-notifier
```

Error occured when I try to update npm to version 7. Now I uninstall version 7 and there is version `6.14.11` as it was at the begin, but I still can't call npm install

---

I uninstalled Node.js and installed again but didn't help

---

In folder:

```
C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm
```

I have `package.json` file and inside this file:

```
"bin": {
    "npm": "./bin/npm-cli.js",
    "npx": "./bin/npx-cli.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "update-notifier": "^2.5.0",
```

I tried to remove this line but result is the same, cannot find module `update-notifier`

Comment: Are you using nvm?

Comment: What is nvm? I'm using npm

Comment: After you uninstall node have you checked that the npm and node paths not exist?

Comment: Nvm is a node version manager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution in this question:
[npm-cli-js-not-found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24721903/npm-npm-cli-js-not-found-when-running-npm)

Copy the directory named npm from your installed node path (In my case the npm directory was available in `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules`).

Navigate to `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules` and paste the copied npm directory there.