# "cannot find module npm-cli.js"

Tags: node.js, npm

I've been at this for hours, and I've tried endless things and reinstalled NodeJS so, so many times.

I'm on Win10.  I cannot run npm, it seems to have some PATH error I cannot get around this:

> Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program
> Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'

This path looks screwy, I know.  I've removed any roaming entries in the PATH var for nodejs or npm.  Only

> C:\Program Files\nodejs

remains at this point.

Is there any real solution that works for Win10 every time?

I'll do anything at this point.  I've tried so, so many things that I found here or a dozen other sites.

I'm not trying to do anything special.  I just want to run npm at the command line successfully--update itself, check itself, anything.  No matter how it's invoked, I get the error above.

I mean, what ***should*** the PATH look like?  How can I make this thing happy?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Which version of Node are you installing? Are you just downloading the MSI file from https://nodejs.org/en/download/ or are you doing something different? I have Node 14.15.4 / NPM 6.14.10 on Windows 10 and they work just fine in Powershell, CMD and Git Bash

Comment: FYI, this isn't a path issue. It looks like it is correctly resolving `npm` to `C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm` (or `C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd`). It's the contents within that command / script that are resolving things incorrectly. I suspect you may have a `.npmrc` file in your user profile that has an incorrectly configured `prefix`

Comment: @Phil but look at that whole path.  node_modules\npm\bin repeated twice.  That can't be right, right?

Comment: @Phil I have v14.17.5 installed.  Yes, from same site you pathed above.

Comment: The final path comes from the `npm` script file (either `npm` for bash or `npm.cmd` for Powershell / CMD) and it figures that out from any configured `prefix`. Can you run `node.exe`? if so, try running `node.exe "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g` and see what it shows

Comment: If it shows `C:\Users\<your username>\AppData\Roaming\npm` (as it does on mine), perhaps try deleting that folder

Comment: @Phil I did a repair on my NodeJS install and now it's added the PATH entry:

[C:\Users\breck\AppData\Roaming\npm]

But just know, I still do have that entry I'd had originally:

[C:\Program Files\nodejs]

Still same symptoms with the repair (and the new PATH addition).

I will try to *delete* that ...\Roaming\npm folder as you suggested.

Comment: And yes, running node.exe as you specified did indeed yield the [C:\Users\breck\AppData\Roaming\npm] folder.

Comment: I deleted the AppData\...npm and \npm-cache folders.  Relaunched cmd and get the same results.

Comment: The only thing I got to (seemingly?) work was running [SET PATH=C:\Program Files\Nodejs;%PATH%] before running npm.  A hack from here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24721903/npm-npm-cli-js-not-found-when-running-npm