# trying to run openAI app: cannot find module when calling 'npm run dev'

Tags: node.js, npm, modulenotfounderror, openai-api

Hej there! I am trying to run the openAI app (using this tutorial: https://beta.openai.com/docs/quickstart/build-your-application and the readMe on Github). Node is installed and I repaired it, installed it in the Programmes folder as well as the folder where I installed the openAI application. Do you have any idea how to solve this problem?

This is the output:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\<name>\openAI\openai-quickstart-node\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\laura\.03_myDevelopment\openAI\openai-quickstart-node\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'
←[90m    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)←[39m
←[90m    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47←[39m {
  code: ←[32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'←[39m,
  requireStack: []
}
```

Best regards,
Solaris

Comment: did you run ```npm install``` ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24741740/10346275

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've installed the necessary packages using `npm install` in the terminal.

Comment: I have the same problem with same tutorial, except I'm using a Mac. Running `yum install` returns `yum install: error: the following arguments are required: PACKAGE`. The `package.json` name is `"name": "openai-quickstart-node",`. However entering `yum install openai-quickstart-node` returns `No match for argument: openai-quickstart-node`.

Comment: @ehounder I personally use npm, but by what you are saying, I don't think yum allows for the packages to be installed with a single command. You might need to go into your package.json and install all the modules under the dependencies and devDependencies manually. Your name of your project is separate to the packages/modules.

Comment: did run npm install, tried it again just now and still running into the same problem