# Why Electron throws an error says that cannot find "cli.js"

Tags: node.js, npm, electron, node-modules, npm-install

I've tried to install Electron with npm on my computer these days, and it's installation is successful, but when I tried to run Electron, I get an error.

Here are my commands in the Windows Terminal:

```
PS [user profile location]> npm install -g electron

added 91 packages in 7s
PS [user profile location]> electron
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:959
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '[node js location]\node_modules\electron\cli.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:956:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:804:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v18.7.0
```

Comment: Try starting it with npm run command.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the command electron . on the package.json, like this

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "electron .",
},
```

then execute **npm run start**

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that command too.But the same error still exists.

Comment: @xzx7131 A made a little research and someone says that is a node misconfiguration, specifically with the node environment variable [StackOverflow link where read about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24721903/npm-npm-cli-js-not-found-when-running-npm)

Answer (score 1):

After trying to reinstall all kinds of things...

What actually worked was installing Electron globally!

```
npm i electron -g
```

You can follow this tutorial:
https://www.techomoro.com/how-to-install-and-set-up-electron-on-windows-10/

Answer (score 0):

I have this same error too, I did a `yarn install` (`npm install` if you're using npm)

Once that finished I did `yarn start` or (`npm start` if you're using npm)