# npm start not working in react last version

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-start, react-scripts

i was working on React 17.0.2
but today i moved on to React 18.0.2
i faced a problem when using(npm start):
i tried all solutions like installing react-scripts and npm i and uninstalling react modules but nothing worked

```
PS D:\Nageeb\Code\Laravel&React\ecommerce-frontend> npm start 
> ecommerce-frontend@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts start
'React\ecommerce-frontend\node_modules\.bin\' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;

Error: Cannot find module 'D:\Nageeb\Code\react-scripts\bin\react-scripts.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
PS D:\Nageeb\Code\Laravel&React\ecommerce-frontend>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting `node_modules` folder and running `npm i` on the root folder.

Comment: i did it 
the same problem

Comment: Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24741740/18312347. Have you tried this? If the environment variable is fine, would you mind sharing the code base? cause it seems to be an issue with the repo or similar

Comment: i tried it , nothing happend
that's all the code :
https://github.com/NageebDarwish/e-commerce

Comment: i found the solution 
the main folder that the project inside it contain (&) in its name
i deleted it and it worked 
thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution the main folder that the project inside it contain `(&)` in its name i deleted it and it worked

Answer (score 0):

The problem is causing "&" in the name of your folder - "Laravel&React". Try to rename the folder to e.g. "laravel_and_react" and re-run "npm start" again.