# The node package manager (npm) throws error on trying any command

Tags: node.js, npm

I installed Node.js, but whenever I run `npm -v`, it throws this output:-

```bash
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:998
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '../lib/cli.js'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:995:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:841:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\devsa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js:2:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12) {       
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\<username>\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js'
  ]
}

Node.js v18.12.1
```

Whenever I run `$node -v` it works fine and shows the current version number.

I have also tried reinstalling, but it didn't work.

Output for `$ where node` :

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
```

Output for `$ where npm` :

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm
C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd                        
C:\Users\devsa\AppData\Roaming\npm\npm                                                                                  
C:\Users\devsa\AppData\Roaming\npm\npm.cmd
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24721903/npm-npm-cli-js-not-found-when-running-npm

Comment: I tried the solutions there, but they didn't work in my case.

Comment: What is the output of `where npm` and `where node` from cmd?

Comment: Updated the question with the output

Comment: How did you install the nodejs? From the official site or using some other tools like `nvm`?

Comment: Using the Windows installer on official site

Comment: Honestly im out of ideas, sorry, everything had to work. I would try to install different nodejs version seeing this github [issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/45329) which is not resolved. Sorry for not being able to help.

Comment: I think when this happened to me, I had to manually delete as much of NPM as I could find in the file system and then reinstall npm using a Windows installer.