# Cannot find module '../../third_party/github.com/chalk/supports-color'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, angular, angularjs

In my mytuoring-frontend-main project

package.json

```
{
  "name": "app-frontend",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^10.0.11",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.2.12",
    "@angular/common": "^10.0.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "^10.0.11",
    "@angular/core": "^10.0.11",
    "@angular/forms": "^10.0.11",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/localize": "^10.0.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^10.0.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^10.0.11",
    "@angular/router": "^10.0.11",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular": "^2.0.1",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^21.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image": "^23.0.0",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.7.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.30",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.14.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.14.0",
    "@fullcalendar/angular": "^5.3.0",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^5.3.0",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^5.3.0",
    "@fullcalendar/list": "^5.3.0",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^5.3.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^7.0.0",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^5.0.1",
    "@ngx-share/button": "^7.1.4",
    "@ngx-share/buttons": "^7.1.4",
    "@ngx-share/core": "^7.1.4",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^13.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.9.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^17.0.1",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.0",
    "angular-froala-wysiwyg": "^3.2.1-1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.2",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "flexslider": "^2.7.2",
    "fullcalendar": "^5.3.0",
    "jasmine": "^3.6.1",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "moment": "^2.27.0",
    "moment-range": "^4.0.2",
    "moment-timezone": "0.5.31",
    "ng-circle-progress": "^1.6.0",
    "ng-multiselect-dropdown": "^0.2.10",
    "ng2-dragula": "^2.1.1",
    "ng2-file-upload": "^1.4.0",
    "ng2-smart-table": "^1.6.0",
    "ng2-timezone-selector": "^0.2.4",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^5.6.1",
    "ngx-editor": "^5.0.0",
    "ngx-extended-pdf-viewer": "^6.1.0",
    "ngx-paypal": "^8.0.0",
    "ngx-quill": "^12.0.1",
    "ngx-restangular": "^6.0.0",
    "ngx-sharebuttons": "^8.0.5",
    "ngx-slick-carousel": "^0.5.1",
    "ngx-smart-modal": "^7.4.1",
    "ngx-socket-io": "^3.2.0",
    "ngx-stripe": "^10.1.2",
    "ngx-toastr": "^13.0.0",
    "pace-js": "^1.0.2",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "quill": "^1.3.7",
    "rxjs": "^6.2.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.0.0-rc.0",
    "select2": "^4.0.13",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "tooltip.js": "^1.3.1",
    "tslib": "^2.0.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.11.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1000.7",
    "@angular/cli": "^10.0.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^10.0.11",
    "@angular/language-service": "^10.0.11",
    "@types/chartist": "^0.11.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.12",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.8",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.112",
    "@types/node": "^14.6.0",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.2",
    "karma": "~5.1.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-cli": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.4",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.10.2",
    "tslint": "~6.1.3",
    "typescript": "^3.9.7"
  }
}
```

I have ran in this command in terminal. `npm run start` . But there are some errors.

```
D:\paypal\mytutoring-frontend-main>npm run start

> app-frontend@0.0.0 start
> ng serve

DEPRECATED: The 'defaultProject' workspace option has been deprecated. The project to use will be determined from the current working directory.
An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '../../third_party/github.com/chalk/supports-color'
Require stack:
- D:\paypal\mytutoring-frontend-main\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\src\terminal\caps.js
- D:\paypal\mytutoring-frontend-main\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\src\terminal\text.js
- D:\paypal\mytutoring-frontend-main\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\src\terminal\index.js
- D:\paypal\mytutoring-frontend-main\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\src\index.js
- D:\paypal\mytutoring-frontend-main\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\src\architect.js
- D:\paypal\mytutoring-frontend-main\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\src\index.js
- D:\paypal\mytutoring-frontend-main\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\dev-server\index.js
- C:\Users\Blad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\node-modules-architect-host.js
- C:\Users\Blad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\index.js
- C:\Users\Blad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\src\command-builder\architect-base-command-module.js
- C:\Users\Blad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\src\command-builder\architect-command-module.js
- C:\Users\Blad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\src\commands\build\cli.js
- C:\Users\Blad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\src\command-builder\command-runner.js
- C:\Users\Blad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\cli\index.js
- C:\Users\Blad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\init.js
See "C:\Users\Blad\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-nfsWWM\angular-errors.log" for further details.
C:\Users\Blad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\util\hostReportError.js:4
    setTimeout(function () { throw err; }, 0);
                             ^

Error: Cannot find module '../../third_party/github.com/chalk/supports-color'
Require stack:
- D:\paypal\mytutoring-frontend-main\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\src\terminal\caps.js
- D:\paypal\mytutoring-frontend-main\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\src\terminal\text.js
- D:\paypal\mytutoring-frontend-main\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\src\terminal\index.js
- D:\paypal\mytutoring-frontend-main\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\src\index.js
- D:\paypal\mytutoring-frontend-main\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\src\architect.js
- D:\paypal\mytutoring-frontend-main\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\src\index.js
- D:\paypal\mytutoring-frontend-main\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\dev-server\index.js
- C:\Users\Blad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\node-modules-architect-host.js
- C:\Users\Blad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\index.js
- C:\Users\Blad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\src\command-builder\architect-base-command-module.js
- C:\Users\Blad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\src\command-builder\architect-command-module.js
- C:\Users\Blad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\src\commands\build\cli.js
- C:\Users\Blad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\src\command-builder\command-runner.js
- C:\Users\Blad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\cli\index.js
- C:\Users\Blad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\init.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:995:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:841:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\paypal\mytutoring-frontend-main\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\src\terminal\caps.js:4:23)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'D:\\paypal\\mytutoring-frontend-main\\node_modules\\@angular-devkit\\architect\\node_modules\\@angular-devkit\\core\\src\\terminal\\caps.js',
    'D:\\paypal\\mytutoring-frontend-main\\node_modules\\@angular-devkit\\architect\\node_modules\\@angular-devkit\\core\\src\\terminal\\text.js',
    'D:\\paypal\\mytutoring-frontend-main\\node_modules\\@angular-devkit\\architect\\node_modules\\@angular-devkit\\core\\src\\terminal\\index.js',
    'D:\\paypal\\mytutoring-frontend-main\\node_modules\\@angular-devkit\\architect\\node_modules\\@angular-devkit\\core\\src\\index.js',
    'D:\\paypal\\mytutoring-frontend-main\\node_modules\\@angular-devkit\\architect\\src\\architect.js',
    'D:\\paypal\\mytutoring-frontend-main\\node_modules\\@angular-devkit\\architect\\src\\index.js',
    'D:\\paypal\\mytutoring-frontend-main\\node_modules\\@angular-devkit\\build-angular\\src\\dev-server\\index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Blad\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\@angular\\cli\\node_modules\\@angular-devkit\\architect\\node\\node-modules-architect-host.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Blad\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\@angular\\cli\\node_modules\\@angular-devkit\\architect\\node\\index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Blad\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\@angular\\cli\\src\\command-builder\\architect-base-command-module.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Blad\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\@angular\\cli\\src\\command-builder\\architect-command-module.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Blad\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\@angular\\cli\\src\\commands\\build\\cli.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Blad\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\@angular\\cli\\src\\command-builder\\command-runner.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Blad\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\@angular\\cli\\lib\\cli\\index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Blad\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\@angular\\cli\\lib\\init.js'
  ]
}

Node.js v18.12.0
```

I have already installed angular in my windows10 system. and when I run `ng v` , it runs well. the result here.

```
D:\paypal\mytutoring-frontend-main>ng v
DEPRECATED: The 'defaultProject' workspace option has been deprecated. The project to use will be determined from the current working directory.

     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 15.0.5
Node: 18.12.0
Package Manager: npm 8.19.2
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 10.2.5
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, localize, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1000.8
@angular-devkit/build-angular   0.1000.8
@angular-devkit/core            10.2.4
@angular-devkit/schematics      10.2.4
@angular/cdk                    11.2.13
@angular/cli                    10.2.4
@angular/http                   7.2.16
@schematics/angular             10.2.4
rxjs                            6.6.7
typescript                      3.9.10
```

Comment: try this comment from github:  https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1071#issuecomment-225526216

Comment: there's a problem with your dependencies, maybe try deleting your `node modules` folder and running `npm i` again . further you can delete npm cache or if persisted, even changing your node version

Comment: Now node-sass version is node-sass@4.14.1. So I have downgrade my node version to ^14.16.0. After done it, when I ran "node -v", I can see node version like this  v14.16.0.   But when I ran "npm -v", I have some errors. here.  internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Blad\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'
←[90m    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint ...

Comment: there's a tool called `nvm` that lets you use multiple node versions at the same time, this repository provides `nvm` for windows https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows. if you're working with node js `nvm` will always come handy, specially on linux, changing node version without `nvm`  would be a headache everytime.

Comment: about your current problem, i guess the system path variable  for the npm is messed up, check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/24741740/11968594 and other answers on the question.

Comment: Thank you. I have checked again system path. I have corrected node path. It works well.

Comment: is your original question solved ?

Comment: Yes. I have solved my original error. It seems that it was caused by incompatibility between the node version and the Angular version.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to not recongize module '../../third_party/github.com/chalk/supports-color'. Ensure this is installed and placed in your node_modules folder.

Also running another `npm install` would ensure your packages and dependencies are the correct versions and are all present based on any changes your team members or you have made previously to the package.json file.

If this provides the valid solution would you please click the green arrow on my response to inform others of the solution.