# I was getting error while working with npm modules, when I type npm - v it gives module not found error

Tags: node.js, npm, module, node-modules, npm-package

When I type 'npm -v' I got the following error says
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1080
throw error;
Error:cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'

Could anyone find the solution for this problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24721903/npm-npm-cli-js-not-found-when-running-npm I think this is your problem

Answer (score 0):

1. Type "environment" in Start and click on " Edit the System
   environment variables"
2. Click on Advanced tab and "Environment Variables" at the bottom of the prompt
3. Select "Path" in the System Variables section, and "Edit"
4. Find your Nodejs entry, and change it to "C:\Program Files\nodejs"
5. Don't forget to restart the terminal so the change applies

Comment: Its not working and the error shows again

Answer (score -1):

I think this is the nodejs path problem in your system. So, check your env variable.

Comment: Even I changed the env variables error still persist

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).